# Displaying a Crystal Report without paging

Tags: asp.net, .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am in the process of migrating an existing web application from `.Net 1.1` to `.Net 4.0`

The application originally used Crystal Reports 11 and in the process of migration we are upgrading these reports to use Crystal Reports 13 (CRVS 2010) SP3.

For one of the reports, the requirement is to show the entire data in a single page (the report viewer control is turned off). I am just not able to get it to work in the migrated report.

Thr properties set are:

`DisplayToolbar` : `false` (crystal report viewer control)

`SeparatePages` : `false` (crystal report viewer control)

`Keep Together` on all sections : `true` (in the rpt file)

`Suppress Blank Section` :`true`

As I did not have much in page footer I set the `Reserve Minimum Page` footer property. I also set `Clamp Page footer` property

However when my report is displayed in the page, I observe blank lines in between the content like in the sample below.
[image]

These gaps appear right at the point where I would have had the page break if I had enabled paging. This makes my report look odd on the web page. With the old application which used previous version of CR this was not the case. Is there a way I can fix this without having to revert to paging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is a defect in the current implementation. We have instead decided to revert to 12.x where this issue is not present. It is mentioned that this issue has been fixed in the new SP but we didnt try it out.

Refer SAP support forum:
http://scn.sap.com/thread/3284720